# KSQL Steam-table Left join partially (and silently) fails to populate values

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am joining a stream with a table. The result of the join is only partially successful. Some of the values are accurately populated while others are null. I checked to make sure that the values exist in both the table and stream, and that the column used to join on is the key for both.

I'm using confluent to load the topics that are reading from tables in MSSQL using the jdbc.

Im then creating the stream and table from the corresponding topics using KSQL, and the data is all in JSON format.

The time stamps on the missing data in the table is older than that of the stream.

```
create stream casecode_contract_stream as select ct.projectid, ct.casecode, cs.isTrue from contract_stream cs left join casecode_table ct on cs.projectid = ct.projectid;    

select * from casecode_contract_stream limit 1;
1532034321292 | 706083 | null | null | true

ksql> select * from casecode_contract_stream where casecode is not null limit 1;
1532034321292 | 705147 | 705147 | data1 | true

select * from casecode_table where projectid = 705147;
1532033878462 | 705147 | 705147 | data1 

select * from casecode_table where projectid = 706083;
1532033878463 | 706083 | 706083 | data2 

select * from contract_stream where projectid = 705147;
1532034321292 | 705147 | 705147 | true

select * from contract_stream where projectid = 706083;
1532034321292 | 706083 | 706083 | true
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The result depends on the (non-deterministic) processing order. It's a known issue and work in progress to make processing order more deterministic.

It can happen that the records from the stream-side are processed before the records are added to the table-side. For this case, as you specify a left-join, the stream record will be joined with NULL.

Comment: The timestamp on the table data precedes that of the stream. Are you suggesting that the there is a separate processing time that does not correspond to the timestamp?

Comment: Timestamp synchronization is not perfect atm -- it's a know issue and we are currently working on a fix: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3514 -- after KAFKA-3514 is fixed, table records with smaller timestamps will be processed first to populate the table. Atm, the only known workaround (not sure if possible to apply) is to start with two empty topic, write the table data first and wait until they are processed and afterward write the stream data. Of course, if you have existing topics with data, this is not possible to do